# как делать цикл по символам массива строк в C

Tags: c, строки, char

Сделаем массив строк:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char **string_array[] = {"digital", "analog", "tester", "smartphone", NULL};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       printf("%s\n",string_array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

как сделать цикл который бы пробегал по буквам сначала 'd' потом 'i'... потом также с другой строкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *string_array[] = {"digital", "analog", "tester", "smartphone", NULL};

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(string_array[i]); ++j)
        printf("-%c",string_array[i][j]);
    puts("");
}
```

Так сойдет?